# How to build a library and make .dll that has a declaration but no definition of a function in windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am building a library(assume xyz) to create a .dll file(assume xyz.dll) in windows using Visual Studio 2022.

From xyz.dll, I would like to call a function in application. So I declared the function as extern in abc lib and tried to make a call, but it is giving "unresolved external symbol" error. I tried `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` also. But nothing worked.
In Linux, it is happening very smoothly.Eg:

### app.c

```
#include<stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
extern void call_foo();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
void main()                                                                                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                                                                                   
       call_foo();                                                                                                                                                         
}
void call_stack()                                                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                                                                   
      printf("Entered %s\n", __func__);                                                                                                                                   
}
```

### lib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
extern void call_stack();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
void call_foo()                                                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                                                                   
    printf("Entered %s\n", __func__);                                                                                                                                                       
    call_stack();                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

Now Building like:

```
$ gcc -c -fPIC lib.c 
$ gcc -shared -o lib.so lib.o
$ gcc app.c lib.so
```

But I am not able to do the same in windows. It is giving "unresolved external symbol call_stack ". Any changes I need to do, so that xyz.dll should be produced without any errors?

Note: I am able to achieve this functionality(dll to app call) using function pointer & call back. But I am looking much simpler solution like any flag, keyword, linker option in .vcxproj file etc.
Thank you.

Comment: Thee headline sounds like reverse-PIIMPL, and that sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: wolfssl.dll is a library, linkable to applications. wolfMQTT is an application by default... Why not try adding the wolfMQTT source files to the wolfssl.dll project so the core of wolfMQTT gets compiled into the library. Then have wolfMQTT application project no longer compile the base sources, just the example app itself. Now wolfSSL with wolfMQTT built as part of the library should be able to make calls to wolfMQTT with no issue (I suspect you'll need to add the wolfMQTT headers to the proper wolfSSL source file to make this work but yeah... that's the approach I would try anyway.

Comment: You could also do this dynamically via `GetProcAddress` (use `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` to get the exe's module handle).